# Are "glow in the dark" bedsheet safe

Tags: infant, safety

We are planning to buy a "glow in the dark" blanket as our seven month old daughter finds it fascinating. However are there any health concerns with using "glow in dark" stuff. I understand they use radium for the glow effect. Does it cause any long term health hazard.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it uses radium?

Comment: I don't know where in the world you live, but at least in the US, unless it's 50 years old, it shouldn't be using radium. If it *is* using radium, then it's obviously not safe at all.

Comment: No. They don't use radium. Most common these days is Strontium aluminate. Not good if eaten, but no other health hazards.

Comment: Actually a blanket that has dye that is poisonous when chewed on is probably not a good idea for a 7 month old.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Note: I can't post images, please edit if you can]

I've never heard of glow in the dark bedsheets. They definitely do not contain radium, which is deadly poisonous. There was a mass poisoning of workers, the [Radium Girls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radium_Girls) in 1917, if you want to read a horrible story.

Today's glow in the dark materials need to be charged with light and then glow for some time, from minutes to hours, in contrast for the radioactive ones, which glow for years.

Phosphorescent materials are typically oxides or sulfides, doped with rare earths. These materials are mostly harmless (but not made to be ingested), you can find material safety datasheets for many materials [here](http://glowinc.com/glow-in-the-dark/MSDS/msds.aspx).

Of course, that does not help you, because you don't know if the overseas manufacturer really used a safe material.

If you want to do something really cool, here are some totally safe [ideas](https://web.archive.org/web/20130321120824/http://www.glowforum.com/gallery/images.php):
[image: Stars]

The green stuff lasts longest, the red ones glow for only a short time. If you'd like to do a correct image of the sky, you can buy a cheap star projector to get the positions on the ceiling and then paint the stars in place.